# Decompressing LZ4 compressed data in Spark

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark, lz4

I have LZ4 compressed data in HDFS and I'm trying to decompress it in Apache Spark into a RDD. As far as I can tell, the only method in `JavaSparkContext` to read data from HDFS is `textFile` which only reads data as it is in HDFS. I have come across articles on `CompressionCodec` but all of them explain how to compress output to HDFS whereas I need to decompress what is already on HDFS.

I am new to Spark so I apologize in advance if I missed something obvious or if my conceptual understanding is incorrect but it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I believe you want to look into the docs and examples for `SparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile()`.

Comment: I'm 80% sure `textFile` performs decompression on gzipped data. Did you try it? Does it not decompress your files transparently?

Comment: I have tried `textFile` and no it does not decompress the data.

Comment: @Daniel - `textFile()` does indeed decompress gzipped data (I've used it many times like that), but not data compressed with LZ4. For that, you'll need `newAPIHadoopFile()`.

Comment: gzip is not an option on huge file because decompression cannot be parallelized while bz2 (but to slow) and lz4 are.

Answer (score 1):

Spark 1.1.0 [supports](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2399) reading LZ4 compressed files via `sc.textFile`.
I've got it working by using Spark that is built with Hadoop that supports LZ4 (2.4.1 in my case)

After that, I've built native libraries for my platform as described in [Hadoop docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html) and linked them them to Spark via `--driver-library-path` option.

Without linking there were `native lz4 library not loaded` exceptions.

Depending on Hadoop distribution you are using building native libraries step may be optional.