# how to read lz4 compressed data using fileStream of spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

in spark streaming, I want to use fileStream to monitor a directory. But the files in that directory are compressed using lz4. So the new lz4 files are not detected by the following code. How to detect these new files?

```
val list_join_action_stream = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](gc.input_dir, (t: Path) => true, false).map(_._2.toString)
```

I know the textFile function could read .lz4 format data. But I'm using spark streaming with fileStream function...

Comment: Are the files in the input directory named with the `.lz4` extensions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decompressing LZ4 compressed data in Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985704/decompressing-lz4-compressed-data-in-spark)

Comment: yes, the files in the input dir are named with .lz4 ext

Comment: @vanekjar  i 'm using fileStream in spark streaming, the question you give me is using textFile.

Comment: Spark uses Hadoop input format for reading files. So `.textFile` and `.fileStream` with `TextInputFormat` should be the same. Hadoop should handle the input compression transparently. What is your Hadoop version?

Comment: @vanekjar my hadoop version is hadoop 2.6, my experiment shows they are different...

Comment: @user2848932, did you find solution to spark stream .lz4 files? If so, can you please share the details. I'm having the similar streaming challenge, but with .ORC files.